# Cogs / Background Taks etc

Tags: python, discord.py

All

to be able to handle commands, I have a cog, and it's being loaded successfully and working correctly. The use case is, we have a command called !info, this code needs to be executed when the user types in !info, or after a certain internal.  The user part is done. Now to execute on interval, I have a background task. This task is called on a regular basis and is working.

The issue is this, the code for this command is under

```
# Commands
@commands.command()
# async def info START
async def info (self, ctx, *args):
```

Which is the same code, which needs to call from the

```
# Background Task
@loop(seconds=20)
async def background_handler(self):
```

Logically, I should call the same "info" function, as we don't want to duplicate the code, however, I don't think I have context available in the background task. Still new to this and working through it.

Any suggestion or if technically I should be using a different approach

Thanks
S

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new method with the code from your `info` funcion and call this in both the command and background task:

```py
class YourCog(commands.Cog):
    def info_function(): # make it async if you need to
        # code from info command

    # Commands
    @commands.command()
    # async def info START
    async def info (self, ctx, *args):
       self.info_function()
```

If that background task is in another cog you can get the cog object with `bot.get_cog('Name')`

```py
# Background Task
@loop(seconds=20)
async def background_handler(self):
    cog = self.bot.get_cog('YourCog')
    cog.info_function()
```

If this function needs a context then you could pass the context if you have it from the command and otherwise use things like [`Bot.get_channel(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel) to get a predefined channel to send messages to. Just depends on what your command is actually doing.